# Powershell 2: Easy way to direct every bit of output to a file?

Tags: powershell, redirect

I have a script that generates output of various forms - mostly standard output and error channels.

I have tried things like:

```
script.ps1 > $somefile 2>&1
script.ps1 | tee-object <args>
script.ps1 | out-file <args>
```

I've also tried start-transcript / stop-transcript. All of these methodologies have their drawbacks, or just don't plain seem to work.

What is the closest powershell equivalent of the UNIX-style invocation:

```
myScript.ps1 > $somefile 2>&1
```

When I try the above command in powershell, I see all output on console, and a 0-length file called 'output' is left behind. What gives?

EDIT: Okay, I believe most of my problem lies in the fact I'm using Write-Host, which I think bypasses the standard output stream. However, I am very worried that if I switch my Write-Host statements to Write-Output, then I'll end up corrupting the return values of all of my functions, or seriously screwing my script up some other way.

What is my most prudent option of dealing with the Write-Host entries so that I can reliably capture all output and errors to the same file? Also, I'm using colorization capabilities from Write-Host... I'm guessing I'll have to give that up if I'm looking to dump to log files.

Or even better, is it possible to set up a command-line argument, say, '-console' that controls whether Write-Host or something else is used? My script is initially being run dozens of times a day manually and interactively. It will then run once an hour every day for years to come, where logs of all output/errors will be desired.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing

```
myScript.ps1 > $somefile
```

You can do

```
powershell myScript.ps1 > $somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd focus my efforts on start and stop transcript. I use it in a 3-tier system involving a client calling a script on a server that proxies a call to another server via PSRemote, and it does a splendid job for me. The output is clean and easily parsed.

It fails with native commands, unless you pipe its output to Out-Default. And you can't get to fancy with it. One transcript is all you get at a time, but one's enough.

Comment: I think you're right. Between the time I posted this and the time you responded, the best I've been able to come up with is a start-transcript and stop-transcript. Thanks for your idea!

Comment: Good read on logging with PowerShell scripts, shows an issue he had with using transcript cmdlets. http://blog.magenic.com/blogs/daniels/archive/2008/07/12/_2200_Logging_2200_-Script-Output-in-Powershell.aspx